# Delete a row by index from pytorch tensor

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a pytorch tensor of size `torch.Size([4, 3, 2])`

```
tensor([[[0.4003, 0.2742],
     [0.9414, 0.1222],
     [0.9624, 0.3063]],

    [[0.9600, 0.5381],
     [0.5758, 0.8458],
     [0.6342, 0.5872]],

    [[0.5891, 0.9453],
     [0.8859, 0.6552],
     [0.5120, 0.5384]],

    [[0.3017, 0.9407],
     [0.4887, 0.8097],
     [0.9454, 0.6027]]])
```

I would like to delete the 2nd row so that the tensor becomes `torch.Size([3, 3, 2])`

```
tensor([[[0.4003, 0.2742],
     [0.9414, 0.1222],
     [0.9624, 0.3063]],

    [[0.5891, 0.9453],
     [0.8859, 0.6552],
     [0.5120, 0.5384]],

    [[0.3017, 0.9407],
     [0.4887, 0.8097],
     [0.9454, 0.6027]]])
```

How can I delete the nth row of the 3D tensor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```py
import torch
x = torch.randn(size=(4,3,2))

row_exclude = 2
x = torch.cat((x[:row_exclude],x[row_exclude+1:]))

print(x.shape)
>>> torch.Size([3, 3, 2])
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69133050/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

The operation below selects all but one "row":

```py
import torch

torch.manual_seed(2021)

row = 2
x = torch.rand((4, 3, 2))

new_x = x[torch.arange(1, x.shape[0]+1) != row, ...]

print(new_x.shape)
# >>> torch.Size([3, 3, 2])

print(x)
# > tensor([[[0.1304, 0.5134],
# >          [0.7426, 0.7159],
# >          [0.5705, 0.1653]],
# > 
# >         [[0.0443, 0.9628],
# >          [0.2943, 0.0992],
# >          [0.8096, 0.0169]],
# > 
# >         [[0.8222, 0.1242],
# >          [0.7489, 0.3608],
# >          [0.5131, 0.2959]],
# > 
# >         [[0.7834, 0.7405],
# >          [0.8050, 0.3036],
# >          [0.9942, 0.5025]]])

print(new_x)
# > tensor([[[0.1304, 0.5134],
# >          [0.7426, 0.7159],
# >          [0.5705, 0.1653]],
# > 
# >         [[0.8222, 0.1242],
# >          [0.7489, 0.3608],
# >          [0.5131, 0.2959]],
# > 
# >         [[0.7834, 0.7405],
# >          [0.8050, 0.3036],
# >          [0.9942, 0.5025]]])
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone wondering how to reduce any other dimension (e.g., removing a column) of the tensor, you need to add the corresponding `dim` parameter for `torch.cat`.

```py
>>> import torch
>>> x = torch.randn(size=(4,3,2))
>>> row_exclude = 2
>>> x = torch.cat((x[:, :row_exclude, :], x[:, row_exclude+1:, :]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: Sizes of tensors must match except in dimension 0. Expected size 0 but got size 2 for tensor number 1 in the list.
>>> x = torch.cat((x[:, :row_exclude, :], x[:, row_exclude+1:, :]), dim=1)
>>> print(x.shape)
torch.Size([4, 2, 2])
```

Answer (score 0):

For now, I have this slow method (it works for me because I call this function infrequently).

```
def delete_row_tensor(a, del_row, device):
    n = a.cpu().detach().numpy()
    n = np.delete(n, del_row, 0)
    n = torch.from_numpy(n).to(device)
    return n
```

I am still looking for efficient torch methods.

Comment: Have you seen my answer? It is as efficient as it gets...

Comment: Yes, I saw your answer after posting it. And I am using your implementation. Thanks!

Comment: okay. I posted the comment because you marked another one as answer and posted one of your own, both after I posted mine =] so didn't really know if you saw it haha

Comment: My bad. I thought your answer was the one is was using. But I am using Vinson's answer. Mostly for ease of understanding. But thanks for posting the answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
import torch
import numpy as np

x = torch.randn(size=(100, 200, 300)) 

index = np.array(range(x.size(0)))  # get dim 0 index

del_index = np.array([29, 31, 49])  # the raw you want to delete

new_index = np.delete(index,del_index,axis=0) # get new index
    
new_x=x[new_index,:,:]              # get new x which del row

# code as a function
def delete_tensor_row(x,delete_raw_list,dim)

    index = np.array(range(x.size(dim)))

    del_index = np.array(delete_raw_list)

    new_index = np.delete(index,del_index,axis=dim)
    
    if dim==0:
        new_x=x[new_index,:,:]
    if dim==1:
        new_x=x[:,new_index,:]
    if dim==2:
        new_x=x[:,:,new_index]

    return new_x
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).